# Laptop charger voltage fluctuation

Tags: laptop, power-supply, power, charging, charger

I had sent my laptop(Dell inspiron 5520) for repair as it wasn't getting charged at all. The battery was working fine though. The technicians at the service centre told me that the voltage fluctuations produced by the laptop charger has affected the motherboard. The desired output of the charger is 19.5v. I have checked the output of my charger and the output is varying between 17.0v - 19.5 v . Is this normal or do I have to buy another charger?

Comment: You really need to perform this test when the charger is under load.

Comment: Probably same technician who has already repaired your laptop can check also the charger and advice.